# How to define two implementations in C?

Tags: c

I want to have two implementations A.h A.c, and B.h B.c
They bot declare the same method(s) and the only difference is the implementation in the .c files.

But now I've got this Linker Error for duplicated symbols.

Comment: How do you expect your code to choose between the implementations?

Comment: The trick is... only to compile one of them.

Comment: C has functions, not "methods".

Comment: What are you [actually hoping to achieve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Defining two implementations is a (broken) solution to a problem you haven't told us.

Comment: They are both in the same project, and I want to switch between them in a third file.

Comment: Are you trying to bind statically (create 2 different versions of the program), or dynamically ( one version of the program, but different implementations called in different circumstances) ?

Comment: the second - different implementations called in different circumstances

Comment: Why you put my question on hold, if its not clear for you, move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the names.

There are no "namespaces" in C. They were added to C++. In C everything at the global scope has to have a unique name.

So prefix your stuff

```
A_Function1
A_Function2

B_Function1
B_Function2
```

etc.

If you only need 1 implementation (say one is for Mac and other for Windows) then of course only link one in or use `#if` to turn one off

```
// a.h
#if USE_A
...
#endif  // USA_A

// a.c
#if USE_A
...
#endif  // USE_A
```

Same for B. Then when you compile you can use

```
cc -DUSE_A=1
```

Otherwise if you need to switch implementations at runtime (say OpenGL vs DirectX backends) this is often done with function pointers.

You make yet another file with pointers to functions. You then fill in those pointers to functions with either functions from implementation A or B. All other files only reference the function pointers.

```
// a.h
int A_SomeFunc(int arg1);

// a.c
#include "a.h"
int A_SomeFunc(int arg1) {
  ...
}

// b.h
int B_SomeFunc(int arg1);

// b.c
#include "b.h"
int B_SomeFunc(int arg1) {
  ...
}

// virtual.h
extern int (*SomeFunc)(int arg1); 

void Init(int implementation) // 0 = A, 1 = B

// virtual.c
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int (*SomeFunc)(int arg1);

void Init(int implementation) {
  switch (implementation) {
    case 0: // use A
      SomeFunc = A_SomeFunc;
      break;
    case 1: // use B;
      SomeFunc = B_SomeFunc;
      break;
  }
}
```

Now somewhere at the start of your program you need to call `Init`. Then other files can include `virtual.h` and will use whatever implementation you selected in `Init`.

To take it to the next level, put `SomeFunc` in a struct.

```
struct SomeAPI {
 int (*SomeFunc)(int arg1);
};
```

Now change Init to fill out SomeAPI

```
void Init(struct SomeAPI* someAPI, int implementation) {
  switch (implementation) {
    case 0: // use A
      someAPI->SomeFunc = A_SomeFunc;
      break;
    case 1: // use B;
      someAPI->SomeFunc = B_SomeFunc;
      break;
  }
}
```

Now you've effectively made the virtual functions of C++ classes. Other modules would do something like

```
struct SomeAPI api;
Init(&api, 1);  // choose B
int result = api.SomeFunc(someIntArgument);
```

Or

```
struct SomeAPI* pAPI = malloc(sizeof(SomeAPI));
Init(pAPI, 1); // choose B
int result = api->SomeFunc(someIntArgument);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really helpful! I'm translating from Java and I actually have more then two implementations of an interface.